# How to Dynamically add a View using Auto Layout

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, autolayout

I have this view(pink) in scrollview :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ZBSU.png)

I want this :

when I tap on 'add' button 'new element' button shows and when I re-tap on 'add' button , 'new element ' button hides but I want also this :

when 'new element' button is visible the pink view's height is like in the photo , but when 'new element ' button is not visible the pink view is to decrease the height , but I don't be able to set this situation by auto layout.

Can you help me?

Comment: You could add the constraints in the Storyboard editor that they match to one of your states. Then place the Constraints you have to edit to achive your second state in your ViewController class as outlets. And in these outlets you can set the value of the Constraints programatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this: new element button have boolean "isHidden"
in case true or false just set your pink view height (pink.frame.size.height),if is hidden button decrease the height if is not hidden increase the height

```
if newElementButton.isHidden { pinkView.frame.size.height = 50 }
 else { pinkView.frame.size.height = 100 }
```